# How do I make two database query calls in one activity in android

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I would like to make a sql query and puts it in a TextView. I am able to do it for a ListView by following tutorials/examples on using adapters/dbHelpers. I am getting `CursorIndexOutOfBoundException` will leads me to believe I am not using the Cursor properly.

This is the code in onCreate:

```
    TextView summaryTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.summary);
    sumAllAmounts = iouHelper.getSumAllAmounts();
    startManagingCursor(sumAllAmounts);
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(iouHelper.getSumAllAmounts(sumAllAmounts)));
    summaryTV.setText(String.valueOf(iouHelper.getSumAllAmounts(sumAllAmounts)));
```

`sumAllAmounts` is a Cursor which is returned by the database helper executing the sql command. I know the sql query is correct because I tested it using `SQLite Database Browser`. And I am able to get it to work on a `ListView` using `ArrayAdapters`.

The query should return 2 column: id and amount. The `helper.getSumAllAmounts(Cursor)` will return the second column `Cursor.getInt(1)` and it gets converted to a String to be displayed on the TextView. `TextView.setText(String.valueOf(int))`

Please guide me as to where I messed up. Thanks.

EDIT:

```
Code for DB helper function:
public Cursor getSumAllAmounts() {
        return (getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT _id, SUM(amount) FROM ious", null));
    }

public int getSumAllAmounts(Cursor c){
        return (c.getInt(1));
    }
```

Schema for the DB:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ious (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, type TEXT, amount INT, description TEXT, date String);");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bug is in `helper.getSumAllAmounts(Cursor)`. You are passing an invalid column index into a cursor.get* function. I'd need to see your query projection string and your calls to cursor.get* to tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Perhaps what is wrong here is you need a call to cursor.moveToFirst() to position the cursor?

Comment: Also, your query won't work. You can't select _id and sum(amount). Try just selecting sum(amount) and then update your `c.getInt(1)` to `c.getInt(0)`